# ¿Como renombrar carpetas de un directorio?

Tags: python-3.x, archivo, tablas

No tengo mucho tiempo en el desarrollo de scripts, sin embargo me surge la duda de como podría tomar una columna que llamaremos inicial, que se encuentra en una hoja de excel comprarla con las carpetas de un directorio y si cumplen la igualdad cambiaremos su nombre por columna final que se encuentra en la misma hoja y ademas si no encuentra la carpeta poder crearla.

He buscado ejemplos pero me supera en cuanto a conocimiento del lenguaje.Mi idea en principio es ajustar el orden del directorio con la columna inicial para que se mantenga el orden al hacer os.rename(directorio,columna final ) y la columna final. Pero ese paso no lo puedo descifrar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
import os
import pathlib,shutil,glob
from posixpath import abspath
from os import listdir, path
import pandas as pd 
import numpy

 #contenido= os.listdir(directorio)
 #directorio = pathlib.Path(r'E:\EXPEDIENTES_PRUEBA')


df = pd.read_excel( r"E:\P1\info_fincas_1.xlsx")
directorio = (r'\\sdominio\Rentas_Catastro_Valoraión\EXPEDIENTES')

abs_path = os.path.abspath(directorio)
contenido = os.listdir(abs_path)
cold_old = df['Inicial'].tolist()
cold_new = df['final'].tolist()
nombre=[]
indices_final=[]
codigo_final = []



for carpeta in contenido:
    nombre.append(os.path.join (directorio,carpeta))

 
  try:
      for old_name,new_name in zip(cold_old,cold_new):
      os.rename(old_name,new_name)
      pass
    

  except FileNotFoundError:
         if not os.path.exists(old_name):


  
#FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] El sistema no puede encontrar el 
 archivo especificado, pero es porque ya  esta creado dentro de 
 directorio, como hago para saltarme esta excepción.
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! [type here]

Comment: "tomar una columna que llamaremos inicial, que se encuentra en una hoja de excel comprarla con las carpetas de un directorio y si cumplen la igualdad cambiaremos su nombre por columna final" y porque simplemente no intentas modificar la carpeta, y si la funcion tira un error (porque no existe) la salteas y sigues con la proxima?

Comment: Ya avance un poco mas en el código pero ahora el error que me envía es que el archivo no se encuentra. pero esto sucede porque ya ha sido creado con anterioridad utilice un try y  except para que continué  recorriendo las carpetas evitando los archivos sin embargo me vuelve a saltar el error

Comment: @gbianchi como le haría para saltarla ?

Comment: explica bien en tu pregunta tu problema, y algun experto en python podra ayudarte...

Comment: @gbianchi  Mi pregunta es como dentro del código ya mostrado haría una sentencia para saltarme si me solicita que el archivo no fue encontrado pero es porque ya la carpeta a sido creada antes de que el código se ejecute ?

Comment: pero no estas iterando uno por uno?

Comment: no entiendo.. el codigo que escribiste, si no hace absolutamente nada en la excepcion, deberia funcionar....

Answer (score 0):

te dare una respuesta ajena a tu codigo. talvez te sirva mas alla de corregir el tuyo, ademas de explicar el error en el tuyo.

---

## SOLUCION

El proceso del algoritmo nuevo sera el siguiente.

1. acceder a la informacion del excel
2. acceder al listado de carpetas de la direccion
3. evaluar la existencia de la carpeta en la direccion
4. si existe, cambiar su nombre... si no existe, crear la carpeta con el
   nombre

para este algoritmo se requiere de los siquiente modulos

1. os
2. pandas
3. shutil

asumiendo que las direcciones en las strings son correctas tanto en el script que mostraste como en el documento excel la estructura general del programa es la siguiente.

```
importar modulos
import os
import pandas as pd
import shutil
```

1º ACCEDER A LA INFORMACION DEL EXCEL

```
df = pd.read_excel( r"E:\P1\info_fincas_1.xlsx")
```

2º ACCEDER A LOS ARCHIVOS CONTENIDOS EN EL DIRECTORIO

```
directorio = r'\\sdominio\Rentas_Catastro_Valoraión\EXPEDIENTES'
abs_path = os.path.abspath(directorio)
archivos = os.listdir(abs_path)
```

3º EVALUAR LA EXISTENCIA DE LA CARPETA EN LA DIRECCION

el metodo `df.iterrows()` genera una lista en donde cada elemento es una fila del excel correlativamente.

Al indexar la columna id_predial de la respectiva fila estamos accediendo a la string contenida en este `fila["id_predial"]`.

Una vez identificado el nombre de carpeta en la direccion, se consulta si su nombre se encuentra en la lista que contiene los nombres de archivos de la direccion destino. Si el nombre sí está, devuelve un `True` y se almacena en la variable condicion, de otra forma un `False`. Este dato booleano se usa en la condicional if.

Si se encontro el nombre de carpeta indicado por esa fila en la columna id_predial, en el listado de carpetas en la direccion destino, entonces se modifica el nombre de la carpeta en la direccion destino usando la string contenida en la columna id_final de la misma fila.

Si no se encuentra el nombre de carpeta contenido en la columna id_predial de la fila, entonces se procede a crear una carpeta en la direccion destino usando la string contenida en la columna id_final de la fila.

```
for fila in df.iterrows():
     condicion = fila["id_predial"] in archivos
     if condicion:
         pass
     else:
         pass
```

4º SI EXISTE, CAMBIAR NOMBRE::: SI NO, CREARLA

```
for fila in df.iterrows():
     condicion = fila["id_predial"] in archivos
     if condicion:
        nombre_nuevo_carpeta = fila["id_final"]
        nueva_carpeta_con_dir = os.path.join(directorio,nombre_nuevo_carpeta )
        antigua_carpeta_con_dir = os.path.join(directorio,fila["id_predial"])
        os.rename(antigua_carpeta_con_dir, nueva_carpeta_con_dir)
     else:
        nombre_nuevo_carpeta = fila["id_final"]
        nueva_carpeta_con_dir = os.path.join(directorio,nombre_nuevo_carpeta )
        os.mkdir(nueva_carpeta_con_dir )
```

---

## CODIGO FINAL

El codigo final es el siguiente

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import shutil

df = pd.read_excel( r"E:\P1\info_fincas_1.xlsx")

directorio = r'\\sdominio\Rentas_Catastro_Valoraión\EXPEDIENTES'
abs_path = os.path.abspath(directorio)
archivos = os.listdir(abs_path)

for fila in df.iterrows():
     condicion = fila["id_predial"] in archivos
     if condicion:
        nombre_nuevo_carpeta = fila["id_final"]
        nueva_carpeta_con_dir = os.path.join(directorio,nombre_nuevo_carpeta )
        antigua_carpeta_con_dir = os.path.join(directorio,fila["id_predial"])
        os.rename(antigua_carpeta_con_dir, nueva_carpeta_con_dir)
     else:
        nombre_nuevo_carpeta = fila["id_final"]
        nueva_carpeta_con_dir = os.path.join(directorio,nombre_nuevo_carpeta )
        os.mkdir(nueva_carpeta_con_dir )
```

Adjunto el link a mi drive para que descargues el programa y no se generen errores al copiar y pegar.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1r3b1vLb-cX0EtPC35TIMp3WYltxSImwn/view?usp=sharing

---

### OBSERVACIONES

El codigo desarrollado segun el paradigma declarativo

ERRORES POSIBLES:

1. Las strings con las direcciones tienen algun separador equivocado
2. Las strings con las direcciones alguna esta equivocada
3. La direccion principal de carpeta no existe
4. El archivo en excel no existe en la direccion indicada

Estare atento a tus comentarios por correcciones.

Comment: porfavor indica en que linea del codigo se genera el error. aparece en el mismo mensaje. de otra forma, podrias adjuntar el archivo excel en el problema para yo probar el programa de inicio a fin.

Answer (score 0):

Disculpas, el error creo que ya fue solucionado, solo era agregar un iterarador que vinculara los indices con la fila. Copió el codigo nuevamente al que asigne la variable indice. El error me saltaba al ingresar en la segunda linea de condición.

```
for **indice**,fila in df.iterrows():
 **condicion = fila["id_predial"] in archivos**
 if condicion:
    nombre_nuevo_carpeta = fila["id_final"]
    nueva_carpeta_con_dir = os.path.join(directorio,nombre_nuevo_carpeta )
    antigua_carpeta_con_dir = os.path.join(directorio,fila["id_predial"])
    os.rename(antigua_carpeta_con_dir, nueva_carpeta_con_dir)
 else:
    nombre_nuevo_carpeta = fila["id_final"]
    nueva_carpeta_con_dir = os.path.join(directorio,nombre_nuevo_carpeta )
    os.mkdir(nueva_carpeta_con_dir )
```

Lo que si me queda duda es que debo correr el script dos veces ya que la primera vez me da este error.
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado: 'E:\EXPEDIENTES_PRUEBA\6100100111558' -> 'E:\EXPEDIENTES_PRUEBA\61001011155800'

Agradezco la ayuda brindada.

Sobre todo a Marcelo Rivera

Comment: Los agradecimientos se dan _con votos a favor_. Si el error aún está relacionado a tu pregunta, ponla como edición; si es una pregunta nueva, redacta una pregunta nueva (y agrega un enlace a esta de ser necesario).